# Vagrant - Mudando a senha de conexão ssh com a máquina

Tags: vagrant

Bem pessoal, eu estou fazendo uns testes com máquinas virtuais feitas com o Vagrant, mas agora, estou tendo um problema que é o de mudar a senha padrão de conexão com a máquina virtual(Senha padrão: "vagrant").

Segue abaixo o Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "192.168.0.21"
  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = '123'
  config.ssh.insert_key = true
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "wlan0", ip: "192.168.0.21" 
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "192.168.0.21"
    v.cpus = 1
    v.memory = 512
  end
end
```

Percebam que eu mudei a senha pelo config.ssh.password, mas quando tento conectar por ssh pelo terminal, a senha continua a padrão "vagrant".

Quando mudo o username (config.ssh.username) para "root", por exemplo, dá esse problema :

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: root
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
root@127.0.0.1's password:
```

Bem, só falta corrigir este problema, agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação para o VagrantFile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html), o valor da chave `config.ssh.password` é utilizado ao fazer login na máquina virtual via SSH e não para definir a senha em si. A senha é definida na imagem (*box*) que você está utilizando. A mesma explicação vale para a chave `config.ssh.username`.

Caso você queria modificar a senha da sua máquina virtual pode fazer o primeiro login normalmente na VM e só então trocar a senha:

```bsh
$ vagrant ssh
$ passwd
Changing password for vagrant.
Old Password:
New Password:
Confirm New Password:
```

Após esse passo mude o `config.ssh.password` para a senha que você acabou de definir dentro da VM.